# Unwanted behavior of link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

File: shopping_carts_controller.rb

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :extract_shopping_cart

    def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @shopping_cart.add(@product, @product.price)
        redirect_to shopping_cart_path
    end

    def show

    end

   private
       def extract_shopping_cart
           shopping_cart_id = session[:shopping_cart_id]
           @shopping_cart = session[:shopping_cart_id] ?    ShoppingCart.find(shopping_cart_id) : ShoppingCart.create
           session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
       end
   end
```

In app/views/products/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Add to cart', shopping_cart_path(product.id), :method => 'POST', :class=>"btn btn-success" %>
```

is generating

```
http://localhost:3001/shopping_cart.1 link
```

which shows the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /shopping_cart.1
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=
```

In routes.rb

```
resource :shopping_cart
resources :products

devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' },
                 controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

root to: 'welcome#index'
```

What is the problem with the code? I have used a reference app to code my own app.

Answer (score 0):

You are misisng 's' in resources

Comment: i did what you said. now i have another error: No route matches [POST] "/shopping_cart/1"

Comment: Because post method did not take /id... U need to create form for to add product then pass params through firm

Comment: Aur creat anither route like.. Post Shopping_cart/id  => shopping_cart#add_product, as: add_product   and define add_product action 8n controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your routes as:

```
resources :shopping_cart
```

Which gives
[image]

If you add only `resource :shopping_cart` this gives following routes:
[image]

Comment: I did that and now I have another error: No route matches [POST] "/shopping_cart/1"

Comment: @bishisht Do you want to create new shopping cart or update existing shopping cart? If you want to create new shopping cart then no need to send shopping_cart id in the URL. If you want to pass product id than you can use this URL: shopping_cart_index_path(product_id: product.id). You can get the product with this codebase in create action: product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

Comment: I am doing something like if I dont have the cart create a new cart and if  have one add products to that. i have code in github if you have sometime can you check it :) it will be great help :) https://github.com/VisitMeet/visitmeet/tree/acts_as_shopping_cart_implementation